# Jenkins multiline string with '>>' separator on sh block

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to assign to a bash variable a multiline string:

```
 stage('test step') {
      steps {
             sh '''#!/bin/bash -xe

             read -r -d '' MULTI_LINE_VAR_STRING <<EOF
             example row 1
             example row 2
             example row 3
             EOF
             ''' 
      }
}
```

but once executed by Jenkins i receive a generic error:

```
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
```

I need to use the read cmd cause the content is dynamic.

Comment: `<<EOF` has to be on the same line as the command. But anyway, why not `MULTI_LINE_VAR_STRING="stuff"`, why the read?

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for the input, i tried also putting the <<EOF in the same line but still the same error. I'm using the read because the content is supposed to be dynamic coming from a multiline text parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The line has to be exactly `EOF`, nothing in front of after it.

```
stage('test step') {
      steps {
             sh '''#!/bin/bash -xe

             read -r -d '' MULTI_LINE_VAR_STRING <<EOF
             example row 1
             example row 2
             example row 3
EOF
             ''' 
      }
}
```